# Como hacer que Formatter añada en lugar de sobreescribir

Tags: java

```
    private static void compareAndWrite() {
        
    
        
        if(ra.getAccount()==(acc.getAccount())) {
            

            try {
                writer=new Formatter("nuevomaest.txt");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            writer.format("%-16d %.2f%n", ra.getAccount(), acc.combinar(ra));
        }   
        
    }
```

> Tengo un programa que abre dos archivos y compara los registros. Si dos registros tienen una coincidencia, el método compareAndWrite() escribe un nuevo archivo dónde viene reflejado el registro con coincidencia. El problema es que este método es llamado siempre que hay una coincidencia y sobresescribe todo el tiempo el nuevo archivo  con lo que al final sólo refleja un registro.
> Mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo puedo hacer que no sobreescriba?¿

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nunca utilicé la clase Formatter pero prueba lo siguiente:

```
static Formatter writer = null;

private static void compareAndWrite() {
    if(ra.getAccount()==(acc.getAccount())) {
        try {
            if (writter == null)
                writer=new Formatter("nuevomaest.txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        writer.format("%-16d %.2f%n", ra.getAccount(), acc.combinar(ra));
    }   
    
}
```

espero te sirva.

Comment: Me sirve para esto y en lo sucesivo. Mil gracias.